# How to speed up Selenium Webdriver test through RC in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am having a Selenium Test speed issue for a while now. I currently have the following:
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.0
- Selenium Standalone Server 2.53.0
- Selenium IEDriverServer 2.53.0 (32 bit)

When I run the tests on my local machine everything seems fine, the tests run with an acceptable speed.
However when I run the tests through RC, each test takes twice the time, it's so slow.

My configuration is as follow:

From my code I use:

```
public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

public static RemoteWebDriver RemoteDriverInstance { get; set; }

RemoteDriverInstance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());

Instance = RemoteDriverInstance;

From the VM (the machine in whcih the tests will run)
```

I use:

```
-jar C:\Selenium\RC\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Selenium\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe
```

Attempted solutions:

- Before I was using Selenium IEDriverServer 2.53.0 (64 bit), then I downgraded to 32 bit, this has not changed anything.

Now I am stuck. Has anyone faced this issue? This is a major hurdle as the aim of the Automation Tests is to be run on multiple machines, even Virtual Machines.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to update your Selenium standalone server and your IE driver server to version 3.0 . Internet Explorer is known for its high speed so you could try Google Chrome witch is running much faster and executes your code better (less errors finding elements).

I hope I was able to help you